# Run Xdotool on Rasperry PI as user "www-data"

Tags: php, shell, raspberry-pi2, xdotool

I'm using xdotool on rasperry pi to refresh iceaweasel browser.
Now, I want to reload the webpage after the server in LAN is booted.

For this I write a PHP script on Raspberry (refresh.php):

```
<?php
 exec("sh /var/www/refresh.sh");
?>
```

resfresh.sh

```
export DISPLAY=:"0.0"
XAUTHORITY=/home/pi/.Xauthority
xdotool getactivewindow
xdotool key F5
```

If I start the PHP script from console, the refresh is working!
If I start the PHP from external browser, the refresh not working!

That's the Apache error-log:

```
No protocol specified
Error: Can't open display: (null)
Failed creating new xdo instance
```

I think, there's a problem with xdotool and the user www-data.

Could anybody help me?

Comment: its because www-data doesn't have rights to execute a system tool like xdo, infact you can try any other system tool to run by this script and most probably it won't run.

Comment: and is there any solution? also if i run the shellscript with sudo it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add www-data permission to execute system tools

DISPLAY=:0 xhost + local:www-data

On your script
/refresh.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
export DISPLAY=:0 && xdotool key F5
```

On your php file

```
<?php
shell_exec("/refresh.sh " . $phone);
?>
```

then add executable permission to your php file

```
sudo chmod +x refresh.php
```

Execute the php file via URL and your good to go.